# Form query with pivot table

Tags: mysql, forms, laravel

In form below my user share document access with other users. 
How to increase my selector to show me only user who are not shared with this document yet? `Document` and `User` has pivot table `document_user`

```
 <select type="text" name="user" class="uk-select">
        <option disabled selected>Choose from contacts</option>
        @foreach($company->users as $contact)
           //@if (something)
            <option value="{{ $contact->id }}">{{ $contact->first_name}} {{ $contact->last_name}}</option>
           @andif
        @endforeach
    </select>
```

Document = $document

Tables:

user:

- id
- name

document:

- id;
- company_id
- name

document_user:
 - company_id
 - user_id

Comment: What is the relation between user and document?

Comment: `public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'document_user');
    }`

Comment: and user    ` public function documents()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Document::class, 'document_user');
    }`

Comment: could you please add the table structure of the two tables to the question. I think you should have  a [many to many relation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) `hasmany` in user shoulld change to `belongs to many`

Comment: I added, check please

Comment: is it `company_id` in document_user table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

From your table structure I believe you should have the `many to many` relation.

**User.php**

```
public function documents()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Document::class, 'document_user');
}
```

**xx.blade.php**

```
<select type="text" name="user" class="uk-select">
    <option disabled selected>Choose from contacts</option>
    @foreach($company->users as $contact)
        @if(!in_array($contact->id, $document->users->pluck('id')->toArray()))
            <option value="{{ $contact->id }}">
                {{ $contact->first_name}} {{ $contact->last_name}} 
            </option>
        @endif
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: user can have access to many different documents, so this solution not full, I need to check if user user already shared with this doc, his name should not be in the select options list.

Comment: what is the `document` variable name in the view?

Comment: it is `$document`

Comment: I tried already this way, but nope, selectors doesn't show users :((

Comment: @PhilippNoris a `!` is added to the condition. That was a typo. Try now.